# Correr un archivo de Python con Laravel

Tags: python, laravel, script, laravel-7, keras

Tengo mi proyecto de Laravel y quiero correr desde el controlador un archivo Python.
Tengo varias dudas al respecto, veran, lo que quiero hacer es que el usuario suba una imagen, esta pase a un archivo de python y con el algoritmo determine cual es la respuesta de la imagen, para esto cree una red neuronal convolucional con python, la entrené y guarde los resultados en un modelo.h5
Al estar en la vista de laravel, el usuario sube una imagen, esa imagen pasa como parametro a python, en python se lee el modelo.h5 y devuelve una respuesta:

```
if($request->hasFile('imagen')){
        $imagen = $request->file('imagen');
        
        $process = new Process(['python', './Prediccion.py'. scapeshellarg($imagen)]);
        $process->run();

        if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
            throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
        }
        $process->getOutput();
        
        if ($process == 0) {
            return view('Resonancias.ADC', compact($imagen));
        }
        else if ($process == 1) {
            return view('Resonancias.difusion', compact($imagen));
        }
        else if ($process == 2) {
            return view('Resonancias.flair', compact($imagen));
        }
        else if ($process == 3) {
            return view('Resonancias.t1', compact($imagen));
        }
        else if ($process == 4) {
            return view('Resonancias.t2', compact($imagen));
        }
        else {
            return redirect()->back()->with('alert', 'Imposible predecir tu imagen, asegurate de subir una resonancia real');
        }
        
    }
```

y esto es de python:

```
import numpy as np
import sys
from keras.preprocessing.image import load_img, img_to_array
from keras.models import load_model

longitud, altura = 150, 150
modelo = './modelo/modelo.h5'
pesos_modelo = './modelo/pesos.h5'
cnn = load_model(modelo)
cnn.load_weights(pesos_modelo)
php_param = sys.argv[1]

def predict(file):
  x = load_img(file, target_size=(longitud, altura))#grayscale=True
  x = img_to_array(x)
  x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
  array = cnn.predict(x)
  result = array[0]
  answer = np.argmax(result)
  if answer == 0:
    print("ADC")
  elif answer == 1:
    print("Difusión")
  elif answer == 2:
    print("Flair")
  elif answer == 3:
    print("T1")
  elif answer == 4:
    print("T2")

  return answer

predict(php_param)#php_param
```

este es mi form de imagen:

```
<section class="bg-primary" id="show" style= "background-image: url(/img/resonador.jpg); background-size: cover; ">
<div class="container">
    <div class="mx-auto" style="width: 350px;">
        <div class="card" style="width: 23rem; margin-top: -40px">
          <img src="/img/resonancias/default.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
          <div class="card-body">
            <form enctype="multipart/form-data" class="text-center" action="/resonancia" style="margin-left: 80px;" method="POST">
              <label style="margin-right: 90px; font-size:120%"> Subir resonancia </label>
              <input type="file" name="resonancia" >
              <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
              <br>
              <input type="submit" value="Subir" class="pull-left btn btn-sm btn-primary" style="margin-left: -100px; margin-top: 10px">
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <a href="javascript:history.back(-1);" class="pull-left btn btn-sm btn-primary">Atras</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

La action /resonancia va al routes por el metodo POST y este al controlador, hasta ahi todo bien

Mis preguntas son:

1. tengo instalado keras en mi compu, pero si quiero pasar el proyecto de laravel a produccion, que sucede con el archivo python?
2. Donde coloco el archivo python de prediccion y el modelo.h5, antes lo tenia en public pero ahora lo tengo en el proyecto general
3. mi sistema no me devuelve nada, la pantalla queda en blanco, sin alguna respuesta o error, como soluciono esto??

es la primera vez que trabajo de esta forma con python en conjunto con laravel, que me recomiendan??

Comment: Instalar todo lo que tienes en tu entorno local a tu entorno de producción, todos los archivos puedes ponerlos en la carpeta public de laravel. Laravel siempre toma como raiz la carpeta public así que el path es simple

Comment: al seleccionar la imagen el sistema va a /resonancia pero se queda la pantalla en blanco, sabes que pueda ser???

Comment: Ya logre solucionar esto, sin embargo me lanza un error con keras y tensorflow, me dice que lo instale pero no sabria como instalarlos en el entorno de laravel, los tengo instalados en mi compu desde cmd pero supongo que no es lo mismo :(